# How to make this autocomplete with MYSQL database?

Tags: php, jquery

Sorry about my stupid question but my jquery skills are not good. How can i make this [FIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7PC/5/) example to use MYSQL database as a source? Thank you!

The PHP connection part

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "mydb");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("error " .mysqli_connect_error());
}
 $va1= "770032PK";
//perform lookup
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE mycol='$va1'";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

 //print out results
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   echo $row['golqmcm'].",".$row['malakcm'];
```

Some JS code

```
$(function() {
  $( "#choice" ).autocomplete({
    source: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, { label: "Choice2", value: "value2" }, { label: "Choice3", value: "value3" }],
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#choice').val(ui.item.label);
        this.value = ui.item.label;
        $('#prid').val(ui.item.value);
    }
  });
});
```

And HTML part:

```
 <span class="input-group-addon">choices ...</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="choice" name="choice" id="choice">
 </div>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon">value of choices ...</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="prid" id="prid">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="prid2" id="prid2">
</div>
```

Comment: Welp you are probably looking for ajax. (request to a php file, get the request and display it).

Comment: what are you exactly looking for? php code to query your database or javascript to request to your server code?

Comment: @MokshShah the javascript code i need. The source array to be url. I have php request to database.

Comment: Nasko, @Shravan code would help.

Answer (score 1):

May this help you

before your js code you can use fallowing code to add choice and value

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT label, value from table ");
$result  = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

now in your js

```
$(function() {
  $( "#choice" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>],
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#choice').val(ui.item.label);
     this.value = ui.item.label;
    $('#prid').val(ui.item.value);
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I`m not sure but i think your code is not doing autocomplete. No where clause and how to pass variable in your code?